# Creating file content based on user input separated in new lines

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to create a new directory based on user input and then creating a new .txt file in the directory created that has a content from user input

I managed to create the directory as following:

```
echo "Enter directory name"
read dirname

if [ ! -d "/root/test1/test2/$dirname" ]
then
    echo "File doesn't exist. Creating now"
    mkdir /root/test1/test2/$dirname
    echo "File created"
else
    echo "File exists"
fi
```

now i want to take a user input to put into the domains.txt file for example
the script the script should ask:
add your domains:
the user will add a domains like
domain.com
domain2.com
asdf.com
then the domains that taken from the user input will be added to domains.txt file and separated every domain in a new line

the final domains.txt file should look like :

cat domain.txt
domain.com
domain2.com
asdf.com

Comment: How does the user indicate that they are done entering domains? You can probably just do: `echo "enter domains (hit ctl-d when done)"; cat > domains`. (ctl-d is, I think, unix centric.  I think windows wants ctl-z)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can do it:

```bash
echo "Enter domains (empty line to stop):"

read i
while [ ! -z "$i" ]
do
    echo $i >> domains.txt # replace domains.txt with your filename
    read i
done

echo "Result:"
cat domains.txt
```

This code will take domains from the user input and appends them at the end of the file. To stop the loop just enter an empty line.

Small explanation:

- `[ ! -z "$i" ]` checks if `i` is not empty. The loop breaks on empty `i`;
- `echo $i >> domains.txt` appends value of `i` at the end of the `domains.txt`

Comment: thank u, but how i can add this code to the same one who create a new directory

Comment: I think you should have smth like this: https://pastebin.com/SYDyvPVL

Comment: Or like this: https://pastebin.com/ARsW1r6c. Depends from your problem